# Calling COM Library From XBAP

Tags: com, xbap

I am trying to call an old COM library from my XBAP and continue to receive the following exception:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
Message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I have tried adding the HKLM value for RunUnrestricted to no avail.

I don't get anything else but this error when calling the library.  Any ideas?  (This library even works from a pure ASP.NET app)

EDIT:
The COM library makes socket calls to a server.  It looks like that is happenning but somewhere after the last packet, it bombs with this error.

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
     10 8.452945    10.10.10.210          10.10.10.250          TCP      50736 > 22700 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=8
     14 11.459350   10.10.10.210          10.10.10.250          TCP      50736 > 22700 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=8
     21 17.459690   10.10.10.210          10.10.10.250          TCP      50736 > 22700 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish there was a way to cancel a question cause this one is my fault.  I was tunneled through a VPN and just had a bad connection no matter how many times I reconnected.  After a restart, I was then able to interact with the API.

Answer (score 0):

try trusting the site. e.g. trusted sites for IE.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried that in a couple ways...debug launches the xbap right from the local path, deploying and running it produces the same result (running out of debug mode does not display the error, instead goes to a blank page)